# Weird Execution Times

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, execution-time

The problem is about getting some discontinuities in the execution time sequence for various input sizes.
Specifically, I have been trying this code:

```
long double a[2000][2000];
int iter = 0;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    istringstream is(argv[1]);
    int N;
    is >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; ++i){
        for (int J = 0; J <= N; ++J){
            a[i][J]  = (rand()%3+1)*(rand()%4+1);
        }
    }
    clock_t clk= clock();
    for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k){
        for(int i = k+1; i < N; ++i){
            a[i][k] = a[i][k]/a[k][k];
        }
        for(int i = k+1; i < N; ++i){
            for(int j = k+1; j < N; ++j){
                iter++;
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] - a[i][k]*a[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    clk = clock() - clk;
    cout << "Time: " << ((double)clk)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
    cout << iter << endl;
}
```

using g++ 5.4.1 for C++14 compilation.

I tried the code for various values of **N**. However something really weird happens around N = 500. Execution times are listed below. (These are the outputs of the code for various values of N.

```
N = 200 : 0.022136
N = 300 : 0.06792
N = 400 : 0.149622
N = 500 : 11.8341
N = 600 : 0.508186
N = 700 : 0.805481
N = 800 : 1.2062
N = 900 : 1.7092
N = 1000 : 2.35809
```

I tried for N = 500 a lot of times and also on another machine only to get similar results.

Around 500 we have the following:

```
N = 494 : 0.282626
N = 495 : 0.284564
N = 496 : 11.5308
N = 497 : 0.288031
N = 498 : 0.289903
N = 499 : 11.9615
N = 500 : 12.4032
N = 501 : 0.293737
N = 502 : 0.295729
N = 503 : 0.297859
N = 504 : 12.4154
N = 505 : 0.301002
N = 506 : 0.304718
N = 507 : 12.4385
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: With `a` and `iter` being declared as...

Comment: How are these arrays defined? Assuming it's something like `a[N][N]` then your first loop invokes *undefined behavior* (due to the wrong condition `i <= N`)

Comment: a is defined globally as a[2000][2000], iter is declared as int.

Comment: I can confirm that the results above are accurate. Maybe the iterator variable being called more?

Comment: My results differ by wide margin from yours. They are consistent around 500.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee to it. It may go (in rare cases) zero, however "Floating Point Exception" wasn't encountered during the runs.

Comment: @AdityaJain, try to see if it is context switch. Open task manager / gnome system monitor and look at core load. If they start jumping from one to another, then you've context switch. Though such big difference is rather strange. Also compile with -O3 -march=native

Comment: @Incomputable , it doesn't seem like context switch I just checked.

Comment: @AdityaJain, what compiler options do you use?

Comment: g++ @AdityaJain

Comment: This is probably due to cache effects. I don't have time right now to inspect all the code in detail, but it may be worth having a look at http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/ (specifically, Example 5)

Comment: @Incomputable, I compiled with -O3 -march=native -std=c++14.

Comment: @AdityaJain, try to use perf if you’re on linux. It should give you a lot of metrics. Including cache contention.

Comment: Can be reproduced on ideone (https://ideone.com/FGA8UJ) :  400, 600, 800 are ok.  500 fails due to a timeout.  Incredible !

Comment: Adding a srand(42) call makes it run fast. I would assume that the algorithm produces denormalized floats, slowing down floating point execution. see [ideone.com/pNqzt8](https://ideone.com/pNqzt8)

Comment: @Thomas: almost. produces infinity. See my answer.

Comment: @geza It appears you are (at least partially) right. The calculation definitely produces inf and nan. [coliru/6be1b23807d7bb41](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6be1b23807d7bb41)

Comment: @Thomas: thanks, I'll refine my answer that NaN is possible, too.

Comment: Since it appears that dividing by `a[k][k]` is generating nans (because it has become 0.0) check for that before doing the division.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: division by 0 generates +/-infinity in the general case. It becomes NaN only for the case `0.0/0.0`.

Comment: @geza I know that.  `a[i][k]` is also 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program could have floating point overflows and operations which result in NaN for certain cases (if a calculation results in infinity/NaN, then it spreads for your algorithm, so almost all the numbers become infinity/NaN. It depends on `rand()`'s output. If you change the seed with `srand()`, you may not get a slowdown for the `N=500` case).

And, because you use `long double`, the compiled program uses FPU (you can reproduce this with `float` or `double` as well, if you compile for FPU instead of SSE). It seems, that FPU handles infinite numbers much slower than normal numbers.

You can easily reproduce this issue with this snippet:

```
int main() {
    volatile long double z = 2;

    for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        z *= z;
    }

    return z;
}
```

If you use 2 for `z`, this program runs slowly (`z` will overflow). If you replace it with 1, it becomes fast (`z` won't overflow).

You can read more about this here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/thats-not-normalthe-performance-of-odd-floats/

Here's the relevant part:

> **Performance implications on the x87 FPU**
>
> The performance of Intel’s x87 units on these NaNs and infinites is
>   pretty bad. [...] Even today, on a SandyBridge processor, the x87 FPU
>   causes a **slowdown of about 370 to one on NaNs and infinities**.

Comment: I don't see how this explains the specific numbers shown in the snippet...

Comment: @immortal: why?

Comment: Because your explanation should be true for any N from a certain threshold, not 500 specifically... Why is 500 special? Why isn't it happening for 700 or 800? Note the comments mentioning this is reproducible for 500 specifically

Comment: @immortal: it happens for a lot of numbers, not just 500.

Comment: @immortal: you need to re-read the question itself, you'll see other examples as well, not just 500.

Comment: Results are reproducible around 500, not for 600-700 and on. With your current explanation, this shouldn't be the case, rather increase of computations and random numbers should increase the probability for infinite numbers linearly. Your answer doesn't conform the the parameters in question...

Comment: @immortal: have you tried it? It is reproducible everywhere, not just around 500. And if you change the seed, it might not happen for 500.

Comment: @immortal: then you haven't tried hard enough. For example, try it with N = 631.

Comment: Rather than the snippet, add a loop to the end of OP's code to sum all the values in `a` that were used, and output this.  This will demonstrate that the slowdowns come when a `nan` is generated.  I can see this using Visual C++ when using the x87 FPU (using SSE doesn't slow down).

Comment: I think you are right. The difference between `N=500` and others that for ` N=500`  we have a `k` for which `a[k][k]==0.0`, see https://ideone.com/j299eP. Probably just dividing through `0.0` will hurt performance badly. Using ` inf`s latter on makes it even worse.